# Plot occurances on a timeseries with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot occurrences of an event on top of some other graphs of how much time a process took to see if there is a correlation but I can't figure out how to make gnuplot sum the data properly. Since the data is not numerical i'm having trouble applying material related to plotting histograms. Here is my data:

```
"2012-05-15 08:12:49","foo"
"2012-05-15 08:13:01","foo"
"2012-05-15 08:13:58","foo"
"2012-05-15 08:14:03","foo"
"2012-05-15 08:14:10","foo"
"2012-05-15 08:14:17","foo"
"2012-05-15 08:14:33","foo"
"2012-05-15 08:14:35","foo"

...

"2012-05-15 10:31:51","foo"
"2012-05-15 10:32:02","foo"
"2012-05-15 10:32:03","foo"
"2012-05-15 10:32:07","foo"
"2012-05-15 10:32:09","foo"
"2012-05-15 10:32:15","foo"
```

This is extent of the data file, I'd like to have a graph with a line that represents how many events happened at that time

(so I could overlay this onto my other plot that has time of the processing plotted)

Is this possible?

**Edit:** I've tried several combinations of options so far, but none have yielded any readable graph, [here](http://pastie.org/5475243) is the gnuplot file i'm using, `type1.csv` and `type2.csv` are from the graph i'm overlaying. small_report.csv is a 1000 row extract of the 'occurrence' data.

Comment: I should mention I have `gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0`

Comment: When you say you want a line representing how many events happened at a certain time, do you mean every minute?  Every second?  Every day?  What kind of histogram do you want to make?  It would help if you clarify exactly what kind of plots you want to make, and if you posted example code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: by 'certain time' i mean the time resolution of the graph, if the graph is 400px wide for example, then `full_date_range/400` would be the certain time, for example, but i'm not too fussed if that can't be done, i'd settle with per minute or per 10 minutes if there are too many points. Histogram ? Do i need a histogram ? I'll put what I have on in a second

Comment: How are you trying to "sum" the data?  What do you want the plot to look like exactly?  Do you want to count the number of times `"foo"` appears in a certain time interval?

Comment: @mgilson `"foo"` is irrelevant in this case, At this point i'd just be happy with an hourly aggregate of how many times that date appears, even without a graph

Comment: @YarekT -- That's an easy thing to do with python (without the plot).

Comment: @mgilson Its also easy to do in bash, I wanted to have a repeatable solution fed directly from mysql =( http://i.imgur.com/oTWrr.png

Answer (score 3):

The trick here for me was to remember to use timecolumn() when doing math for x-axis (binning).

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "[%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"
binwidth = 30  #30 second bin
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width)
plot "testdata.log" using (bin(timecolumn(1),binwidth)):(1.0) smooth frequency with boxes
```

The above example sums occurrences within given binwidth and plots them across the timeline.

```
$gnuplot --version
gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 4
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to count the number of times a particular date appears with python 2.7:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('datafile') as fin:
    c = Counter(line.split()[0][1:] for line in fin)

for k,v in sorted(c.items()):
    print k,v
```

If you don't have python 2.7, you can mimic this with a `defaultdict` in earlier versions:

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('datafile') as fin:
    c = defaultdict(int)
    for line in fin:
        c[ line.split()[0][1:] ] += 1

for k,v in sorted(c.items()):
    print k,v
```

Now you can use this to make a plot:

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'
set xdata time
plot "<python pythonscript.py" u 1:2
```